# Error con git desde windows 10

Tags: git, git-push

Tengo el siguiente inconventiendo con git

```
Commit failed with error:

The Git process exited with the code -1.073.741.819
```

El siguiente error me sale al hacer commit y push

Al igual cuando intento hacer pull me da como respueta el mensaje que se mustra a continuación:

```
Fetch failed

fatal: UriFormatException encountered
```

Pregunto si es un problema de compatibilidad o algo parecido... 
Cabe destacar que he clonado mis proyectos sin ningún tipo de inconvenientes..
Como también he realizado las configuraciones tanto del nombre de usuario como el email.

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan aportar!

Comment: que te dice `git status`? puede que te estes haceindo algun merge o rebase y estes en un estado extranyo en git

Comment: el git status solo me indica solo los archivos que he modificado!

Comment: se que no es la mejor respuesta pero has probado usar un `GUI` o algun `IDE`, generalmente es mas facil manejar los problemas con alguna interfaz mas experimentada, que conoce todos los comandos

Comment: lo que no entiendo es que recién realizo la clonación del proyecto, trabajo en el y realizo el primer commit y push me sale dicho mensaje que muestro en la pregunta

Comment: de hecho estoy utilizando un IDE pense que era por el ide y por ello me fui directamente al GIT bash, porque tambien utilice tortoiseGIt pero me arroja el mismo mensaje

Comment: El error te da al hacer el `commit` o al hacer el `push` ? o con ambos?

Comment: cuando hago el  `commit` pero de igual forma para hacer el `push` me pide un `commit` pero no me permite hacer el `commit`

Comment: cual es la url del repositorio, y que version de git tienes?

Comment: puede que este link te sea de ayuda https://superuser.com/questions/1114193/when-cloning-on-with-git-bash-on-windows-getting-fatal-uriformatexception-enco

Comment: gracias amigo realmente di con esa información y me ayudo mucho!

Comment: tenia la versión mas actual de git que era la 2.13.1 instale la 2.10 que era la versión que utilizaba anteriormente y me funciona todo! Gracias!

Comment: @JoséRomero sería genial si pudieses publicar la respuesta con toda la información que encontraste y el detalle de tu solución para otros que encuentren tu pregunta y tengan el mismo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era porque Tenia instalada la `versión mas actual de git que era la 2.13.1` la desinstale e instale `la versión 2.10` que era la versión que utilizaba anteriormente Y funciona correctamente. Al parecer es un problema con `la versión 2.13. de git` que generaba ese problema en `windows`.